# Complex deletionquery

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all records of a table which are older then 30 days but keep the last (youngest) 2 records of each ID.
I made some try with limit 2 and group by but did not get near a solution. Has anyone a suggestion?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;

CREATE TABLE  `mytable` (
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`timestamp`)
  );

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
('2014-08-12',22,'data'),
('2014-08-13',22,'data'),
('2014-08-14',22,'data'),
('2014-08-15',22,'data'),
('2014-08-16',54,'data'),
('2014-08-16',22,'data'),
('2014-08-17',54,'data'),
('2014-08-18',54,'data'),
('2014-08-19',54,'data');


Expected Result
2014-08-15,22,data
2014-08-16,22,data
2014-08-18,54,data
2014-08-19,54,data
```

This is what I have so far

```
sql = 'Delete from mytable where timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)';
```

Comment: This data set isn't properly representative is it, because if you dispense with the 30 day rule you'd still end up with the same result!

Comment: and in DB you have `datetime` not `date`, so in data you should have `2014-08-19 12:35:57` for example

Comment: Hi - I was only symplifying the date for better readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE t
FROM mytable t
JOIN (
  SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_ts, ',', 2) AS two_ts
  FROM (
    SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(timestamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS group_ts
    FROM mytable
    WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    GROUP BY id
  ) ag
) tg ON tg.id = t.id AND FIND_IN_SET(t.timestamp, tg.two_ts) = 0
WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

I don't expect it to perform well on big datasets. Though it will work at all until the date groups don't exceed `group_concat_max_len`. Idea for taking k entries per group is taken from a comment on [xaprb blog post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/). Use [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59ac8/2) to play with the query.

Comment: Yes - that does the Job!
I changed the query and removed the first: WHERE timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) in the SELECT. Performace will be better and I think ist not nessesary

Answer (score -1):

**Not correct solution:**

```
DELETE FROM mytable a
WHERE a.timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'
    AND (a.id, a.timestamp) NOT IN (
        SELECT b.id, b.timestamp
        FROM mytable b
        GROUP BY b.id
        ORDER BY b.id, b.timestamp desc
        LIMIT 2
    )
```

---

**Hopefully correct solution:**

```
DELETE FROM mytable a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT c.id, count(1) as cnt
        FROM mytable c
        GROUP BY c.id
    ) b on a.id = b.id
WHERE a.timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'
    AND b.cnt > 2
```

Comment: The Select shows the id only once - same as happend to me

Comment: yes first solution is wrong. can you please test another? I just don't have mysql now to test myself.

Comment: How do you assure that the oldest record are deleted? somehow I miss a order by. Or do I overlook something?

Comment: No need for `ORDER BY` because I simply delete all records which are older that 30 days `AND` which have more than 2 records. If have less than 2 records (by ID), then they are not deleted no matter how old they are. Part which I'm not sure is selecting from the same table as deleting. MySQL sometimes don't like that and you have to find a way to fool him with nested subselects etc. :)